# MessageLogging Policy or new JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, logging, apigee

I am trying to implement Apigee Logging to log several attributes such as Client IP, Total Processing Latency and other custom headers to be retrieved from request and response. They are categorized into BaseLog attributes, SysLog Attributes and AppLog Attributes, each of the latter written on top of the BaseLog. I would like to know what is the best way to log these - Would it be better to use MessageLogging Policy or to use custom JS code to extract and populate the variables?

Lastly, I have to send the logs to a Splunk server. How would one go about doing that ?

Any input would be helpful ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use **JavaScript Policy** to set variables that I want to write them in Log file (e.g., requestDateTime, ip etc.) by using `context.setVariable("variableName", value);`

And then refer those variables in **MessageLogging Policy** like

```
<Message>{requestDateTime}|{client.ip}|{request.content}|{elapsTime}</Message>
```

Actually, Apigee have a lot of useful variable you can use it directly if you don't want to add more JS Policy in your flow but for my situation I want to write a lot of value in my log, some of them have to concatenate with others variable so it is easy to set it before refer in MessageLogging.

However, I just share the method I use.

Hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good practice to minimize the use of JavaScript or any other extension policies since it spawns a thread in message processor everytime these extension policies executes and thus has risk of deadlock as thread-pool has a limit always.

Apigee specially provides message logging policy for logging in async fashion, so you should you try setting all in Post client flow and try using Assign message policy instead of Extension policy for any kind of variable assignments.

Hope this help!